# Using \@author Latex messes up figure captions

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using the `\@author` command from the `authblk` package on Overleaf to list chapter authors per chapter without creating a new title page every time (example below). This works, but as soon as I include the `\@author` command, all figure captions in the chapter get misplaced. Does anyone know how this could happen? The author command and figures are completely unrelated as far as I'm aware (but apparently not), so I don't even know where to begin to try and solve this...

Or alternatively, does anyone have suggestions for another way besides `\@author` to show the authors and affiliations per chapter without using \maketitle?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[dutch,main=english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.~\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}} %<--- use [t] for parbox.
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %<--- better use [t]  here also for parbox to ensure that alignment.

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\graphicspath{ {graphics/} }

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,dutch,english]{cleveref}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\Alph{subfigure}}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}

\newfloat{lstfloat}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{lstfloat}{Listing}
\def\lstfloatautorefname{Listing}
\crefalias{lstfloat}{listing}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  frame=single,
  breaklines=true,
}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[style=nature,sorting=none,giveninits=true,uniquename=init]{biblatex}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

\newcommand{\publicationcite}[1]{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}\fullcite{#1}}

\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
        {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
    {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        
        Titlepage

        

        \vfill

        
        titlepage footer
    \end{center}

 \end{titlepage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{2.55em plus1fil}
\makeatletter

\tableofcontents


\begin{refsection}
    \chapter[Chapter2]{Chapter2}
    \label{ch:cold}
    
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \affil[1]{Affil 1}
    
    \makeatletter
    \@author %without this line, the figure captions are displayed properly
    \makeatother

    Main text of chapter, with figures.
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figurefile.png}
        \caption{This is a test caption}
        \label{fig:fig1}
    \end{figure}

    \lipsum[]
    
    \clearpage
   
    \lipsum[]
 
    \ref{fig:fig1}
    
    %\printbibliography[title=References]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

This is what happens on any page that has a figure:
[image]

Comment: Your code is missing several packages necessary to compile your code fragment. Please check such things before posting.

Comment: Added the full preamble

Comment: You should use `    \makeatletter
    \@author 
    \makeatother` and you must not leave the argument of `\includegraphics{}` empty. Other than that, please specify what you mean that the captions are misplaced. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: I get all the images including their captions at the end, which is expected for figures without floating specifiers.

Comment: Adding the ` \makeatletter \@author \makeatother` doesn't change anything for me. I added a screenshot to the original post. Now it is all text, not just the caption anymore for some reason (I haven't changed anything since posting here)

Comment: The code from your question does not reproduce this output.

Comment: That is so strange... The only difference between this code and mine is that I removed people's personal details and that there are eight chapters instead of one... I even added a some lipsum to the caption and the text in the code above to double check, but if I copy-paste this into a new Overleaf document I get the same problem...

https://www.overleaf.com/7778133613svxngjndhyvf

Comment: might be the same problem as in https://github.com/rrthomas/crop/issues/2

Comment: FYI: earlier revisions of your question did not reproduce the problem because they did not use the `width` key for `\includegraphics`

Comment: Thinking about it, why do you want to use `\author` etc. for chapter authors? All the goodies of a global `\author`, like setting the pdf meta data aren't relevant to this usage. You could just use a custom macro to format the author and affiliation of chapter authors.

Comment: Ah so that is the issue... I don't necessarily need to use that command, but from what I found online that is the only package that does it... I have never built a custom macro before, not sure how to do that. Right now I am manually changing the format in every chapter individually to get around the issue and that works, but I figured there has to be a more elegant solution...

Comment: The minipage worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by placing `\@author` in some kind of box, e.g. a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[noblocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
    \author[1]{Author 1}
    \affil[1]{Affil 1}
   
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \makeatletter
        \@author 
        \makeatother
    \end{minipage}

    Main text of chapter, with figures.
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{mouse.jpg}
        \caption{This is a test caption}
        \label{fig:mouse}
    \end{figure}
    
    test


\end{document}
```